# Vue-router can't render component correctly with Element-UI

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am trying to use Vue-router with Element-UI( http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/quickstart ). But I face some weird condition. Following is my app.js, where I create my vue-router instance.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import ElementUI from 'element-ui'
import locale from 'element-ui/lib/locale/lang/zh-TW'
import 'element-ui/lib/theme-default/index.css'
import myComponent from './vue/page/mycomponent.vue'
import App from './vue/app.vue'

Vue.use(VueRouter)
Vue.use(Vuex)
Vue.use(ElementUI, {locale})

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {path: '/mypage', component: myComponent}
  ],
})

const app = new Vue({
  router: router,
  store: store,
  el: '#v-app',
  render: h => h(App),
})
```

And I put my router-view tag in app.vue .

```
<template lang="pug">
  #v-app
  v-sidebar(:pages="pages")
  router-view
</template>

<script>
import Sidebar from './sidebar.vue'
export default {
  name: 'App',
  data() {
    return {
      pages: [],
    }
  },
  components: {
    'v-sidebar': Sidebar,
  },
}
</script>

<style lang="sass" scoped>
</style>
```

Here is my router-link in sidebar.vue.

```
<template lang="pug">
#sidebar
  template(v-for="page in pages")
    router-link(:to="{path: page.prop}")
      i(class="chevron right icon")
  span {{page.label}}

</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Sidebar',
  data() {
    return {
      defaultProps: {
        label: 'label',
        children: 'children',
      },
      pages:[{label: 'link-1', prop: 'mypage'}]
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

If I strictly go to "/mypage" then it will render correctly. But if I click the link in my sidebar component, the page component won't render completely. I am wonder if there is somewhere I missed or what should I do to fix this kind of situation.